# TypeError: _vm.t is not a function error in Jest Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-i18n

I am using Vue 2 with vue-i18n-composable plugin for translations. I am getting below error in Jest test

```
    [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.t is not a function"
    
    found in
    
    ---> <Bilingual>
           <Root>

  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1884
```

I tried everything on the internet. Nothing fixed this. Can you please help?
Below are the things what I've tried so far

1.

```
const $t = () => {}

const wrapper = shallowMount(Bilingual,{
    mocks:{ $t }

})

expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)
```

2. 

```
describe("Bilingual", () => {
    it("Bilingual component exists", () => {
      const wrapper = shallowMount(Bilingual, {
        mocks: {
          $t: (msg) => msg
        }
      })
      expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)

    })
  })
```

3. 

```
import VueTestUtils from '@vue/test-utils';
VueTestUtils.config.mocks.$t = key => key;
```

I am getting below error for the 3rd try

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
```

4. 

```
const i18n = createI18n({
    messages: {
        en: en,
        dutch: dutch
    },
    fallbackLocale: variables.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
    locale: variables.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
})
describe("Bilingual", () => {
    it("renders successfully", () => {
        const wrapper = shallowMount(Bilingual,{
            i18n
        
        })
      expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true)

    })
  })
```

Can you please help

Bilingual.vue component file

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            {{ t('SAVE', 'en') }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n-composable'

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'Bilingual',
    setup() {
        const { t } = useI18n()
        return {
            t
        }
    },
})
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

main.ts

```
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n-composable'

const i18n = createI18n({
    messages: {
        en: en,
        dutch: dutch
    },
    fallbackLocale: variables.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
    locale: variables.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE
})

app.mount('#app')

const app = createApp({
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    render: (h: (arg0: VueConstructor<Vue>) => any) => h(App),
    i18n,
    router,
    store
})
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of ```Bilingual``` component?

Comment: @Eduardo - added

Comment: @Eduardo - please find the updated code with main.ts

Comment: The error means that there's no VueTestUtils default export. Check the reference regarding how `config` is used.

Comment: @EstusFlask - It's there. I even try using import { config } from '@vue/test-utils'; config.mocks.$t = key => key;. Nothing works :(

Comment: It expects `t`, not `$t`.

Comment: @EstusFlask Yeah. Thanks a lot. I found it just now and was gonna reply here. Then saw your comment. Thanks a lot for all of your help :) . Damn this thing screwed my entire day :@